# How do you compose your shader source in a C++ project?

Tags: c++, opengl

Using WebGL in Javascript I could compose a fragment shader like this:

```
  protected getShader(textureFunc: string, opline: string): string {
    return `
      float getTexel() {
        return getColorAsFloat(${textureFunc}(A, TexCoords));
      }
      void main() {
        setFragColor(${opline});
      }
      `;
  }
```

Here I am building my source with a bunch of dynamic parameters pasted directly in the code. How do you do this in a C++ project? I am looking for novel ways of building dynamic strings instead of `sprintf()` or `std::cout <<`. Do OpenGL programmers use libraries or techniques that facilitate such composition?

Comment: Some tutorial, like [this](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) may help you with shaders and data.

Comment: What part of it you cannot translate to C++?

Comment: How do you manage what, exactly? What are these "dynamic parameters"? Are you talking about doing string find/replace operations? It's not clear what that code would do in JavaScript, let alone what you want in C++.

Comment: @Nicola Bolas: Yes string replacement is the keyword here. Do OpenGL programmers use template processing libraries or they still use primitive sprintf stuff?

Comment: @ybungalobill
Parameter replacement part.

Comment: Edited for clarity

Comment: @Ripi2 I wasn't looking for API or graphics concepts but rather shader code handling.

Comment: You should write your own shaders, in GLSL language (similar to C, but not C). The tutorials show some examples. The code for each shader is a null-terminated "string" you pass to the CPU. It can be in a var or in text-files you read.

Answer (score 2):

C++ lacks a string interpolation feature in the language. An analogous C++ code would be:

```
  std::string getShader(const std::string &textureFunc, const std::string &opline) const {
    return R"(
      float getTexel() {
        return getColorAsFloat()" + textureFunc + R"((A, TexCoords));
      }
      void main() {
        setFragColor()" + opline + R"();
      }
    )";
  }
```

Alternatively you can use some `snprintf`-like formatting library:

```
  std::string getShader(const char *textureFunc, const char *opline) const {
    return Sn::sprintf(R"(
      float getTexel() {
        return getColorAsFloat(%1$s(A, TexCoords));
      }
      void main() {
        setFragColor(%2$s);
      }
    )", textureFunc, opline);
  }
```

Here I use my own `printf` wrapper that returns an `std::string`, with the POSIX positional argument syntax. But you can find any other formatting library that suits the job.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hadn't used C++ in a while I thought it might have evolved. Which looks like it did but not by much.

Answer (score 0):

C++, the core language, *as such* doesn't know anything about shaders. You are almost always going to be using a library. The various available libraries differ.

The library *I* use when doing shader stuff is [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org) and it has a convenient [sf::Shader](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1Shader.php) class. Other libraries will have other classes. Or raw OpenGL will take a raw string as the shader source (again *usually* accessed through a library).

Comment: will check it out for sure. thanks Jesper

Comment: This is a good library for an object oriented approach to OpenGL. With respect to composing shaders does not offer anything. The examples mention to load shaders from files -- which work for static shaders -- or building them using literal C strings which I was hoping to find an alternative to.